# Relating centraliser of product of two elements of a group to the centraliser of one of them

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose G is a finite group and $x, y \in G.$ Then what can we say about the relation of $C_G(xy)$ with $C_G(x)$ and $C_G(y).$         For example, a very obvious one is that if $C_G(xy) = C_G(x),$ then one can see that $C_G(xy) \subseteq C_G(y).$

Comment: You have inspired me to ask a more specific question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202188/groups-with-prescribed-textcx-textcy-textcxy

Answer (score 2):

In general, one has $$C_G(x) \cap C_G(y) \subseteq C_G(xy). \tag{1}$$
Indeed, if $z$ commutes with $x$ and $y$ both, then $$z(xy) = zxy = xzy = xyz = (xy)z.$$

The inclusion in $(1)$ can be extremely strict, however. Indeed, consider $x$ to be arbitrary, and $y = x^{-1}$. Then, $C_G(x) = C_G(y) = C_G(x) \cap C_G(y)$ but on the other hand $C_G(xy) = G$.

---

We also have $$C_G(x) \cap C_G(xy) \subseteq C_G(y). \tag{2}$$
This is a version of $(1)$ by noting that $y = x^{-1} \cdot xy.$ (And of course, $C_G(x) = C_G(x^{-1})$.)
This covers the special case you had. Moreover, since a change of variables lets us switch between $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that this inclusion can also be quite strict. (Simply take $y = 1$.)

---

Thus, we have a two-out-of-three property here. If an element commutes with two of $x, y, xy$, then it must commute with the third. The inclusions being strict also tells us that only commuting with one gives us no information.