# Groups with prescribed $\text{C}(x)$, $\text{C}(y)$, $\text{C}(xy)$.

Tags: group-theory

My question is inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202100/relating-centraliser-of-product-of-two-elements-of-a-group-to-the-centraliser-of), but I want to ask something much more specific.

Let $X,Y,Z$ be finite groups with $1\ne x\in \text{Z}(X)$, $1\ne y\in \text{Z}(Y)$, and $1\ne z\in \text{Z}(Z)$.

Under what conditions does there exist a group (not necessarily finite)  $G\geqslant X,Y,Z$ such that $xyz=1$ and $\text{C}_G(x)=X$, $\text{C}_G(y)=Y$, $\text{C}_G(z)=Z$?

It seems to me that there may be tight restrictions if $(o(x),o(y),o(z))$ is one of $(2,2,k)$, $(2,3,3)$, $(2,3,4)$, $(2,3,5)$ but  beyond that I have no intuition.

Comment: I think this is probably equivalent to asking for which values of $l,m,n > 1$ are the three subgroups generated by the generators self-centralizing in the triangle group $\langle x,y,z \mid x^l=y^m=z^n=xyz=1 \rangle$.

Comment: There is lots of research on this kind of question, but unfortunately the best results are reserved for when the identity "$xyz=1$" is instead of the form $R^n(X, Y, Z)=1$ for $n>1$, e.g. $(xyz)^2=1$ or $[x, y, z]^{47}=1$, or when the groups $X, Y, Z$ are "locally indicable", i.e. all finitely generated subgroups surject onto the infinite cyclic group. Neither situation is the case here.

Comment: Basically, if such a group $G$ exists then the subgroup $\langle X, Y, Z\rangle\leq G$ is a quotient of the group $X\ast Y\ast Z/\langle\langle xyz\rangle\rangle$, which is the free product of $X, Y, Z$ quotiented by the relator $xyz=1$. Therefore, just consider this quotient group, and you are asking if $X,Y,Z$ embed into this group. The literature refers to $X\ast Y\ast Z/\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$ as a "one-relator product", and embedding results like you are after is a "Freiheitssatz". See, for example, [this paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/2045870) of Fine, Howie & Rosenberger.

Comment: Thanks very much @user1729 - that seems to me to be an answer - if you post it as such then I'll accept it and this won't appear to be unanswered.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Okay, done. I should say that the fact that you have $3$ groups rather then $2$ may make a big difference, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is lots of research on this kind of question, but unfortunately the best results are reserved for when the identity "$xyz=1$" is instead of the form $R^n(X,Y,Z)=1$ for $n>1$, e.g. $(xyz)^2=1$ or $[x,y,z]^{47}=1$, or when the groups $X,Y,Z$ are "locally indicable", i.e. all finitely generated subgroups surject onto the infinite cyclic group. Neither situation is the case here.

Basically, if such a group $G$ exists then the subgroup $\langle X,Y,Z\rangle \leq G$ is a quotient of the group $X∗Y∗Z/\langle\langle xyz\rangle\rangle$, which is the free product of $X,Y,Z$ quotiented by the relator $xyz=1$. Therefore, just consider this quotient group, and you are asking if $X,Y,Z$ each embed into this group. The literature refers to $X∗Y∗Z/\langle\langle xyz\rangle\rangle$ as a "one-relator product", and embedding results like you are after is a "Freiheitssatz". See, for example, [this paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/2045870) of Fine, Howie & Rosenberger, and a more recent paper is [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.01627) of Howie and Short.